# Can I set my windows laptop brightness to ZERO or ALMOST zero?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop

I need this because I want to turn my laptop on at home and control it remotely outside, but I don't want the screen to be seen to others. I found this feature in ubuntu, or in some laptop with custom Fn key (which sets brightness to almost zero). I tried some softwares, but it doesn't affect taskbar. Any solutions?

Comment: You don't say what you\'re trying to access it via. Look for 'curtain mode' which just leaves the screen entirely black.

Comment: How about just using RDP and keep the laptop closed (so no lights go on)? Turning the screen black with remote tools is for me just a suspicious behavior, because it it used by scammers.

Comment: why don't just use remote desktop? No one will ever see your screen regardless of the brightness

Answer (score 0):

The following command will set the screen brightness :

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,<Brightness Level>)
```

For example, to set it to 0 and 100 :

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,0)

powershell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,100)
```

However, I'm not sure that this is a good solution to your problem.

(Note: I can't test the above, since I don't have a laptop.)

Answer (score 0):

[NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) may work for you.  It is a useful command line utility.

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility that allows you to do some useful tasks without displaying any user interface. By running NirCmd with simple command-line option, you can write and delete values and keys in the Registry, write values into INI file, dial to your internet account or connect to a VPN network, restart windows or shut down the computer, create shortcut to a file, change the created/modified date of a file, change your display settings, turn off your monitor, open the door of your CD-ROM drive, and more..

It has a command for screen brightness:

https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/changebrightness.html